# Multiple value on between query [PostgreSQL]

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a simple query like this

```
select * from user where xxx between a and b
```

but how if i have multiple input, like xxx, yyy, mmm, bbb.

with same sintax,

```
select * from user where xxx,yyy,mmm,bbb between a and b
```

i want select all user that a and b is beetween xxx,yyy,mmm and bbb. so it will return all user that a and b is match with between creteria.

Thanks

Comment: If you realize that many columns have so much in common, then maybe they shouldn't be different columns. I don't know what the real deal is, but you may want to normalize your database model.

Comment: @Vincent Actually User Table have id, name,..., signuptime, and logoutime. i want to know users that loggin between 13:00 to 15:00 and (16:00 to 17:00). just in case, i want check more then 8 times creteria

Comment: You could for instance create a new table containing the user id, the date and the type of the date (sign up, logout, etc.). This looks like it would suit your needs.

Comment: so how to query that ? i'm new in sql. and i use PHP for database connection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Between Query \[PostgreSQL & PHP\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021812/between-query-postgresql-php)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
WHERE (xxx BETWEEN a and b) 
AND (yyy BETWEEN a and b) 
AND (mmm BETWEEN a and b)  
AND (bbb BETWEEN a and b)
```

If you want all criteria to match. If you want atleast one of them to match, use `OR`  instead of `AND`.

Comment: how if i have more value ? aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,rrr. more then 100 value

Comment: Actually User Table have id, name,..., signuptime, and logoutime.
i want to know users that loggin between 13:00 to 15:00 and (16:00 to 17:00). just in case, i want check more then 8 times creteria

Comment: @Thessa: Then your question is probably misleading. More likely you want something like `xxx BETWEEN a AND b OR xxx BETWEEN c AND d OR …`, not what you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two extra tables to store your dates :

```
date_type (date_type_id, date_label)
user_date (user_id, date_type_id, date_value)
```

Which could be populated that way :

```
date_type (1, 'Sign in')
date_type (2, 'Sign out')
user_date (1, 1, '2010-08-11 02:14:20')
user_date (1, 1, '2010-08-11 02:36:54')
// etc
```

You would then have to do some JOIN to achieve what you want :

```
    SELECT *
      FROM user
INNER JOIN user_date
     USING (user_id)
INNER JOIN date_type
     USING (date_type_id)
     WHERE date_value BETWEEN a AND b;
       AND date_type_id IN (1,2) -- if necessary, you can choose which
                                 -- types to check
```