# Between Query [PostgreSQL & PHP]

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I was asking, but it misleading, so sorry for that. my problem is.

i have a table ranks(rank_id, rank_name, rank_min, rank_max)

is simple if i want know only one rank

```
select * from ranks where (224 between rank_min and rank_max)
```

but if want to know more than one rank, like what is 224, 338, 800, etc

i can use

```
select * from ranks where (224 between rank_min and rank_max) OR (338 between rank_min and rank_max) OR (800 between rank_min and rank_max)
```

but i dont know if may be there is simple way, like using

```
 IN(224,338,800)
```

and how to write a query in PHP that is not fix, i mean in solution 1, using many BETWEEN OR.

in PHP i know if it a siple query like select * from ranks where (224 between rank_min and rank_max). just pas the value. but i dont know how if more then one value

any body have trick and sample how to do that. i hope this question is not misleading

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an idea, I don't know if it's better than making the query dynamically with PHP, but it's worth a shot :

```
SELECT *
FROM ranks
INNER JOIN (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[224, 338, 800]) AS n) TT
    ON n BETWEEN rank_min AND rank_max;
```

You'd just have to make the array dynamically with PHP, but should be much easier than making the whole query.

Comment: owh got, it just an alias name, i dont mention because i dont see 'AS TT'

Comment: hi Vincent. how if want use GROUP BY. ex :

SELECT *
FROM ranks
INNER JOIN (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[224, 338, 800]) AS n) TT
    ON n BETWEEN rank_min AND rank_max
GROUP BY rank_id;

Comment: @Thessa: What are you trying to do with GROUP BY?